# Error while installing the corona sdk plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, lua, coronasdk, playhaven

This is what i a getting on my Corona Simulator Output when i try to install the 'playhaven' plugin. I don't know how to get rid of this.

```
        Build: 2013.1202 Runtime error ?:0: attempt to call field 'request' (a nil value) stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'request'
        ?: in function 'downloadManifest'
        ?: in function 'downloadQueuedManifests'
        ?: in function <?:632>
        ?: in main chunkRuntime error

stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'request'
        ?: in function 'downloadManifest'
        ?: in function 'downloadQueuedManifests'
        ?: in function <?:632>
        ?: in main chunk
```

In case you wanna take a look at my **build.settings** file because after i integrated the plugins into the build.settings file. I recieved the error i showed above.

```
settings =
{
        orientation =
        {
                default = "portrait",
                supported = { "portrait" },
        },

        androidPermissions =
        {
                "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
                "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
                "android.permission.INTERNET",
                "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE",
                "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
        },

        plugins =
        {
                -- key is the name passed to Lua's 'require()'
                ["plugin.playhaven"] =
                {
                    -- required
                    publisherId = "com.playhaven",
                },
        },  

        iphone =
        {
                plist =
                {
                        UIPrerenderedIcon = true,
                        UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = false,
                        CFBundleIconFile = "Icon.png",
                        CFBundleIconFiles = {
                           "Icon.png", 
                           "Icon@2x.png",
                        },
                },
        },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Playhaven is only available to Pro and Enterprise subscribers.  See:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/plugin/playhaven/

Are you a Pro or a Starter?

Comment: I am a starter. When would it available for the starter developers? And the second thing i would like to ask that the same error i am getting for "revmob" too. 
"revmob.lua line "387". "Attempt to call field request a nil value."".
 In that case i dont know what can be the possible reason for that occurance.

Comment: Actually we've opened up Playhaven to Starter accounts.  For RevMob, you will need to contact them. They provide support on their product.

Answer (score 0):

Since you gave so few information on your system and environment I can only guess. It seems that the installer tried to download something (or connect via some protocol) and failed. Did you check your firewall/proxy settings? Maybe connections are automatically refused and you are not aware of it.

Comment: I am working with Corona SDK on windows 7. I am tring to integrate ads in my android application. Whhen i try to run my application it gives this runtime error displayed above.